# Creating table mySQL syntax error

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, create-table

I am trying to run the following query in PHP my admin:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'ibn_table' (
'id' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
'itransaction_id' varchar(60) NOT NULL,
'ipayerid' varchar(60) NOT NULL,
'iname' varchar(60) NOT NULL,
'iemail' varchar(60) NOT NULL,
'itransaction_date' datetime NOT NULL,
'ipaymentstatus' varchar(60) NOT NULL,
'ieverything_else' text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ('id')
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

I get this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''ibn_table' ( 'id' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 'itransaction_id' varchar(' at line 1

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use backtick for quoting columns and table names

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ibn_table` (
    -> `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    -> `itransaction_id` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
    -> `ipayerid` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
    -> `iname` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
    -> `iemail` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
    -> `itransaction_date` datetime NOT NULL,
    -> `ipaymentstatus` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
    -> `ieverything_else` text NOT NULL,
    -> PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    -> ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.12 sec)
```

Comment: ...or just leave them out altogether.

Comment: please use backtick for table name as well. I just executed it and it's working for me

Answer (score 0):

The column names should be in Backticks or just remove quotes. Backticks are to be used for table and column identifiers, but are only necessary when the identifier is a [MySQL reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), or when the identifier contains whitespace characters or characters beyond a limited set (see below) It is often recommended to avoid using reserved keywords as column or table identifiers when possible, avoiding the quoting issue.

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE `ibn_table` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `itransaction_id` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  `ipayerid` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  `iname` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  `iemail` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  `itransaction_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `ipaymentstatus` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  `ieverything_else` TEXT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```